# Gross Basis - Bond Futures

Tags: bond, futures, basis, treasury

Just want to confirm - Gross Basis for Bond A, deliverable into a Future:

Gross Basis [A] = Clean Price [A] - Futures Price x CF [A]

where CF [A] = Conversion factor of Bond A.

Is this due to:
Gross Basis [A] = Dirty Price [A] - Invoice Price [A]

Where:
Dirty Price [A] = Clean Price [A] + Acc Int [from last coupon to now]

Invoice Price [A] = Future Price [A] x CF [A] + Acc Int [from last coupon to now]

simplifying =>

Gross Basis [A] = Clean Price [A] - Futures Price x CF [A]

Thanks